# What is the gradient of deformation gradient $F$?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, continuum-mechanics

Deformation gradient is defined as
$$F_{iJ}=\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial X_J},\;\mathbf{F}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}}{\partial\mathbf{X}},$$
where $\mathbf{x}$ is spatial coordinates; $\mathbf{X}$ is material coordinates.
I wonder whether $\nabla\mathbf{F}$ has physical meaning. Here is my derivation:
$$\nabla\mathbf{F}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{F}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}}\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}}{\partial\mathbf{X}},$$
**where $\nabla$ is the del operator with respect to spatial coordinates**.
Then we interchange the differential order on the right-hand side,
$$\nabla\mathbf{F}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{X}}\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}}{\partial\mathbf{x}}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{I}}{\partial\mathbf{X}},$$
where $\mathbf{I}$ is a second-order unit tensor. Now we have
$$\nabla\mathbf{F}=\nabla_0\mathbf{I},$$
where $\nabla_0$ is the del operator **with respect to material coordinates**.
The answer seems to be zero if there is no mistake in my derivation, but what is its physical meaning?

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

The deformation is the application
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
 \boldsymbol y:\Omega_0      &\longmapsto\Omega\\
               \boldsymbol X &\longmapsto \boldsymbol y(\boldsymbol X)
\end{array}
$$
where $\Omega_0$ and $\Omega$ designate the initial (material) and current (spatial) configurations, respectively.

The deformation gradient has components
$$
 F_{i\alpha}=(\mathrm{grad}\,\boldsymbol y)_{i\alpha}=\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial X_\alpha}
$$
and is also a function of the material coordinates $\boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol X)$.

The gradient of the deformation gradient naturally reads
$$
 (\mathrm{grad}\,\boldsymbol F)_{i\alpha\beta}=\frac{\partial^2 y_i}{\partial X_\alpha\partial X_\beta}.
$$
The deformation mapping is not a function of the spatial coordinates, hence they have no reason to appear at any step.

### Comments

- Since the deformation is a function of the material coordinates, its derivatives are unequivocally defined with respect to the material coordinates.
- It is preferable not to mix up the spacial variable $\boldsymbol x$ (an independent variable in $\Omega$) with the deformation $\boldsymbol y$ (a mapping from $\Omega_0$ to $\Omega$).
  In OP's suggestion, the identity tensor emerges precisely because of this confusion.